# How to update an executed script import in the Python shell after editing it?

Tags: python, shell, ipython

Beginners question. I have started my iPython shell and I am running scripts with the run-command and everything works great. However running a script file and then editing a imported script file and then trying to run it again causes the old imported file to run. So I am guessing python saves some kind of cache for speed. I've tried clear command and such but to no avail.

Basically my problem is this. Two files: function.py and program.py. The program file imports the function. But running the program and then editing the function and then running the program again causes the old function/un-edited version to run.

Comment: Why aren't you running the `program.py` from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside of iPython or the standard Python interpreter, you can use the `reload()` function to reload an imported module.

**Example:**

```
In [1]: import foo
  # make some changes to the foo.py
In [2]: reload(foo)
```

Comment: So adding a reload after the import command in the script file actually does the trick! Would be good with some kind of flush command though.

Answer (score 3):

**For Python 3.4 and above**

```
import importlib
import foo

# Make changes on foo.py

importlib.reload(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Python's reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) function to recompile the module code and reexecute all module-level code - otherwise the Python interpreter will use the stale compiled bytecode (.pyc).
For example:

```
In [1]: import script

In [2]: run script
...

In [3]: reload(script)
Out[3]: <module 'script' from 'script.pyc'>
...
In [4]: run script
```

Answer (score 0):

It's stated [here](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/tutorial.html#the-run-magic-command) that the file gets re-read from disk every time, are you sure the error is not on your side?

Comment: Yes my fault. The script file I run gets updated but not the imported script file in the in the script file I am running.